# AngularJS - Draw border during progress bar CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a time based progress bar and I am using AngularJS for the front end. My progress bar works fine but I want to draw a border or a simple line when the some value changes e.g. when temp1 changes to '1' and then draw another border or line when temp2 changes to '1'.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:20px; border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="progress-bar" ng-style="myCSSStyle(patient)">

    </div>
</div
```

This is the function in my controller:

```
$scope.myCSSStyle = function(patient) {
    return {width: patient.clock * 0.055 + '%', 'background-color': '#1ab394'};
};
```

My CSS:

```
#progress-bar {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I want to check when the value of temp1 changes to '1', a line should be drawn in the progress bar div indicating the time it changed, then again when temp2 changes its value to '1'. Can someone suggest a solution to this problem?

**EDIT:**

This is what I want the progress bar to look like where black and red lines are drawn after temp1 and temp2 are set to 1 respectively

[image]

Comment: where do `temp1` and `temp2` come from ?

Comment: They are just variables I made up and they will be changed to "some" value in the database during any time. When they do, I need to indicate in the progress bar that at the time in the progress bar their value was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the progress-bar out of several elements: bar, black-mark, red-mark. Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kft5vrqu/) (jsfiddle)

```
    <div id="progress-bar">
        <div class="bar" ng-style="myCSSStyle(patient)"></div>
        <div class="black-mark" ng-show="widthValue() > 30"></div>
        <div class="red-mark" ng-show="widthValue() > 50"></div>
    </div>
```

Define rules that trigger black-mark and red-mark visibility.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.patient = {
    clock: 1000
  };

  $scope.myCSSStyle = function (patient) {
    return {
        width: $scope.patient.clock * 0.055 + '%',
        'background-color': '#1ab394'
    };
  };

  $scope.widthValue = function () {
    return parseFloat($scope.myCSSStyle().width, 10);
  };
```

});

**Updates:**

I added button to show/hide black-mark. Red-mark is removed.

[updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lposcgpu/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helped but the black-mark and the red-mark are static but I want the black-mark to appear where the 'bar' position was previously e.g. my bar is moving and when I click a button the black-mark should appear at that position where the bar was positioned when I clicked the button and the bar keeps moving as normal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directly from AngularJS.

So have a class called finished, and style your progress bar as you wish when the progress is done (or "1").

Then, you need a ng-model for that. So in your controller

```
$scope.progress_done = (temp1 === 1);
```

Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:20px; border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="progress-bar" ng-class="finished: progress_done">

    </div>
</div
```

*You didn't provide any details about temp1, or temp2, so I guess "1" means finished.*

Comment: Please see my latest edit for more clear details